# Too difficult or pointless badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, badges

Browsing through the badges, I couldn't help but notice some badges which didn't fit or were simply too difficult to achieve. They've been bugging me and someone needs to bring them up.

I made a list as follows with my problem with each badge:

- [Tumbleweed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed) (0 awarded) - Seems to me that it is bad to achieve this, 0 awarded and generally pointless
- [Stellar Question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question) (0 awarded) - Seems too difficult, our [highest voted puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle) only has 51, and the [most favorites on a question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28494/this-is-important-i-need-you-to-listen) only has 72. Maybe 50 would be  a good barrier considering the [Favorite Question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question) is 25?
- [Illuminator](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/92/illuminator) (0 awarded) - The [Refiner](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/91/refiner) badge (which has only been awarded twice) needs 50. The Iluminator badge needs *500*, that is a massive gap which should be decreased, maybe to 100 or 200?
- [Generalist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/15/generalist) (0 awarded) - Seems too difficult, maybe 10 out of 40 instead of 20?
- [Tenacious](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero) (Both 0 awarded) - To me these seem like these are pointless, it would mean that a load of poor questions would have been posted.
- [Legendary](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary) (0 awarded) - Another one where the badge above, [Epic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic) has only been awarded twice and that requires 50, the Legendary badge requires 150. Maybe 100 would be appropriate.
- [Gold tag badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) (0 awarded) - The [Silver tag badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=silver) has only been awarded twice. That requires 400.  Gold requires 1000. Seems too high.
- [Steward](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/83/steward) (0 awarded) - The [Reviewer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/78/reviewer) badge requires 250, Steward requires 1000, I think this should be halved to 500
- [Booster](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster) and [Publicist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) (Both 0 awarded) - 25 IP addresses has been achieved 21 times, these two badges require 300 and 1000. 1000 definitely needs to be decreased at least, maybe to 500?

I don't want to offend anyone but I'm just raising an issue I have with this site. Can someone help?

Comment: Had a feeling this might get a few downvotes... Can someone explain what the issue is they have with this question?

Comment: The fact that we've never awarded a Tumbleweed badge is actually a) very surprising to me, and b) a _very_ good thing.

Comment: @Emrakul Ditto with Tenacious and Unsung Hero. All of these are not only big-site badges, but also 'consolation prize' badges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Badges are, to the best of my knowledge, consistent in meaning across the entire StackExchange network. This means that smaller communities like ours have much more difficulty in reaching the upper echelons of badge accessorydom, but there's nothing inherently wrong with that.

Didn't the first moderator election happen very recently? That makes this site very new, for StackExchange, whereas gold badges are often awarded for significant effort over long periods of time. As the community grows, you may come to find that the goals set forth for badges are not as remote as you think.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't realize that the badges weren't editable by the site mods.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: Yeah, we can't change badges. Only the over-overlords can do that.

Comment: @Deusovi, I overestimated your power :P

Comment: @Deusovi Those can't do it *just for Puzzling*: they can only do it for the whole Stack Exchange network. What bother me most, though, is that I have higher rep requirements because there is a design just making the site look prettier.